# How to do complex replacements over multiple lines using sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I want to do this substitution in a set of files :

replace :

```
KEY
KEY1|VAL1
KEY
KEY2|VAL2
```

by :

```
KEY
KEY1|VAL1
```

Eg :

```
KEY
KEY|sde
KEY
KEY|45g
```

by

```
KEY
KEY|sde
```

In short, I need to remove the second occurence of KEY \n KEY|VAL pair. I am not good at using sed.

Comment: `sed` has some multi-line capabilities, but I suspect you expect too much of it for your task. If your input is very regular, e.g. each `KEY` repeats exactly twice, and have one `KEYx/VALx` following it, it is simple, but depending on clarifications from you, you might need to look into `awk` or a 'proper' scripting language for your solution.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your problem correctly (and I might not), this is one solution:

```
sed -ne '/^KEY$/{p;n;p;n;n}' file
```

Explanation:

When finding `KEY` in a line by itself:

- `p` - print the line
- `n;p` - go to the next line and print it too.
- `n;n` - skip the next 2 lines.

... and repeat.

*Edit* (explanation continued):

- The `-n` tell `sed` not to print a line unless explicitly directed to do so (with `p`).
- The `-e` is not strictly required here. It says the following string is a `sed` expression.

Comment: Non-standard `-i` command line option works on most flavours of `sed` for inline operations.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e 'N;/key2\|val2/ d' your_file.txt` should do the trick, note the \ is to quote the | otherwise your shell might interprete the command wrongly.

Comment: please see my edit in the question, the val2 - is actually a variable

Comment: That's not why the `|` is escaped (the single quotes already do that. The reason is that in BREs a pipe is a literal character unless it's escaped. In EREs (`sed -r`), you don't need to escape it. Since in this instance you want to match a literal pipe character and you're using BREs, you should *not* escape it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, always good to learn something :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try using awk. Note, only the 2nd instance of your required pattern is changed.

```
# cat file
KEY
KEY1|VAL1
blah
blah
KEY
KEY2|VAL2
junk
junk
KEY
KEY3|VAL3
KEY
KEY4|VAL4
KEY
KEY5|VAL5

$ awk '/^KEY$/&&!f&&!x{s=$0;getline;s=s"\n"$0;f=1;print s;next}f&&/^KEY$/{print s;getline;x=1;f=0;next}1' file
KEY
KEY1|VAL1
blah
blah
KEY
KEY1|VAL1
junk
junk
KEY
KEY3|VAL3
KEY
KEY4|VAL4
KEY
KEY5|VAL5
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it a problem if you use other tools also? I just tried:

`sort "file" | uniq | sed '/KEY2/d'`

You can even emulate uniq using sed, check: http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

Hope that helps

Comment: this would completely alter the file content, i guess that's not intended